# Opening Print Dialog Box in C#

Tags: c#

how to open print dialog box in c# using pdfsharp?? This is my code to print the document but its not opening print dialog box

```
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.Verb = "print";

            //Define location of adobe reader/command line
            //switches to launch adobe in "print" mode
            proc.StartInfo.FileName =
              @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/p /h {0}", pdfFileName);
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            proc.Start();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            if (proc.HasExited == false)
            {
                proc.WaitForExit(10000);
            }

            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            proc.Close();
            KillAdobe("AcroRd32");
            return true;
```

Comment: Does you `pdfFileName` contain any whitespace?

Comment: What does happen -- does the process start?

Comment: I have to wonder about the "CreateNoWindow" - maybe try with false.

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong directory. If you want to print a file from code, you should not be launching Acrobat Reader...

Comment: As @Derek suggested the problem is with "CreateNoWindow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Verbatim from Adobe Reader FAQ...

> AcroRd32.exe /p pathname — Executes Adobe Reader and displays the Print dialog box.
>
> AcroRd32.exe /t path "printername" "drivername" "portname" — Initiates Adobe Reader and prints a file, whose path must be fully specified, while suppressing the Print dialog box.

If you want to print the file without showing the print dialog box you should use the second option.

Comment: thank you but i want to show print dialog box. how can i give 1st option in my code ??

Comment: @VijayP.V You are using the first option ..As Derek suggested don't set createNoWindow to true and also remove the /h,it minimizes the print dialog.

Comment: thanks a lot its working for me i removed /h

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for this.

```
  System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog dialogue = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

  DialogResult dr = dialogue.ShowDialog();
  if( dr == DialogResult.OK)
   {
  // Do something
   }

   dialogue.Dispose();
```

or

```
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
        PrintDialog pdi = new PrintDialog();
        pdi.Document = pd;
        if (pdi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pd.DocumentName = documentName;
            pd.Print();
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Print Cancelled");
        }
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/289705/how-to-open-print-dialog-box-in-my-csharp-applicat